Flutter and Firebase Authentication Issue on ios real device
I'm facing an issue with Firebase authentication in my Flutter app on iOS devices.
Google login works fine if the email I'm trying to sign in with has already been logged in before and exists in the Firebase database. However, if I try to log in with a new email that’s not in the Firebase database, it fails and throws an error.
Email/password login works perfectly for users with valid credentials who already exist in the database.
The issue arises with registration: I can’t register new users. While login with email and password works, registration fails.
Firebase Data:
Apart from the authentication issues, I'm able to retrieve data from Firebase smoothly, and everything works fine within the app.
The problem occurs only on a real iOS device, but everything works fine when I test on the iOS simulator.
When I deploy the app to TestFlight and test it on a physical device, the registration and new Google login functionality don't work.

What does it mean that it doesn't work? Any logs/errors?

That means its not functional as it is working fine in debugging but when once it gets uploaded on testflight, it doesn’t work accordingly. Because i am checking on real device, i am not able to see any errors
